# Rotation of ellipsoid animation

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I have an ellipsoid in Mathematica and I want to make an animation showing what is happening if it is rotating around each axis. In fact, I want to show it in animation that how it can rotate with the angular velocity  $\mathbf{\vec{\omega}} = (\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z)$ in which $\omega_i$ is the angular velocity of rotation around the axis $i(x, y, z) $. It would be great if vector $\mathbf{\vec{\omega}} $ can be shown which the ellipsoid is rotating.  How can I do that?
Here is my code for the ellipsoid:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
pp3d = ParametricPlot3D[{3 Cos[u] Sin[v], 2 Sin[u] Sin[v], 
2 Cos[v]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue], 
MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}}, 
MeshStyle -> (Directive[Thick, #] & /@ {Red, Blue, Green}), 
PlotStyle -> Opacity[1.8], 
PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> False, Boxed -> False];
Normal[pp3d] /. 
Line[x_, ___] :> {Line[x], Line[x /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {-4, b, c}], 
Line[x /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, 3, c}], 
Line[x /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, -3}], ViewPoint -> Default}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `Manipulate` and `Animate`.

Comment: In addition to `Manipulate` and `Animate`, you may also be interested in [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html), which can be used directly in `Graphics3D`, and [`RotationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html).